# Let $(X, \mathcal{A},\mu )$ be measure space. If $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$ then $A \setminus B \in \mathcal{A}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A},\mu )$ be measure space. Prove the following properities:

1) If $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$ then $A \setminus B \in \mathcal{A}$

---

**By def**

A $\sigma-$Algebra on a set $X$ is a collection, denoted $\mathcal{A}$ of a subset of $X$ such that

1. $\emptyset \in A$
2. If $A \in \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow A^c \in \mathcal{A} $
3. If $\{ A_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable famaly sets in $A$ then $\cup^{\infty}_{i=1} A_i \in \mathcal{A}$

---

Assuming $A \in \mathcal{A} , B \in \mathcal{A}$ so by (2) $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$
also $A^c \cup B \in \mathcal{A}$ by (3)

again by 2) $$ (A^c \cap B)^c \in \mathcal{A} $$

that is $ (A^c \cap B)^c=(A^c \cap B)^c =A^{cc} \cup B^c =A \cup B^c$

making $$ A \cup B^c \in \mathcal{A}$$

**Anything wrong, is it a duplicate???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A^c \cup B \in \mathcal{A}$, it follows that $$(A^c \cup B)^c =A\cap B^c=A\setminus B \in \mathcal{A}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct, but seems to take plenty of unnecessary steps.

$$A \cap B^c = (A^c \cup B)^c \in \mathcal A$$

By (2), (3) and DeMorgan.

Also note that $A\backslash B = A \cap B^c$, which seems to not be what you've originally written.